# Phonons and Second Quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, second-quantization, phonons

I have been reading David Tong's notes on Phonons: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/aqm/aqmfour.pdf
I am quite interested in Section 4.1.4, where he quantises the vibrations. First, he defines the most general
(classical) solution $u_{n}(t)$, for the displacement of the $n^{th}$ atom in the chain:

**(A)** \begin{equation}
u_{n}(t) = X_0(t) + \sum_{l\neq0}\bigg[\alpha_l\ e^{-i(\omega_lt-k_lna)} + \alpha_l^{\dagger}\ e^{i(\omega_lt-k_lna)}\bigg]
\end{equation}
and the corresponding momentum:

**(B)** \begin{equation}
p_{n}(t)=P_{0}(t)+\sum_{l \neq 0}\left[-i m \omega_{l} \alpha_{l} e^{-i\left(\omega_{l} t-k_{l} n a\right)}+i m \omega_{l} \alpha_{l}^{\dagger} e^{i\left(\omega_{l} t-k_{l} n a\right)}\right]
\end{equation}
where $l$ indexes the wave-mode ($l = -N/2 , ... , N/2$) and wavenumber: $k_l = 2\pi\ l/Na$, with $N$ the number of unit cells and $a$ the lattice constant. These are treated as operators in the Heisenberg picture, which can be inverted to find the operators $\alpha_{l}$ and $\alpha_{l}^{\dagger}$. My confusion arises in the following step:

> We can invert the equations above
> by setting t = 0 and looking at
> \begin{equation}
> \sum_{n=1}^{N} u_{n} e^{-i k_{l} n a}=\sum_{n} \sum_{l^{\prime}}\left[\alpha_{l} e^{-i\left(k_{l}-k_{l^{\prime}}\right) n a}+\alpha_{l}^{\dagger} e^{-i\left(k_{l}+k_{l^{\prime}}\right) n a}\right]=N\left(\alpha_{l}+\alpha_{-l}^{\dagger}\right)
> \end{equation}

1. How did the last equality come about and where did  $\alpha_{-l}^{\dagger}$ come from?
2. Is it mathematically wrong to just add $u_{n}(t = 0)$ and $p_n(t = 0)$ and rearrange to find $\alpha_{l}$, rather than looking at $\sum_{n=1}^{N} u_{n} e^{-i k_{l} n a}$? If so, why?

If someone can help me parse this step, I'd be very grateful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Using the representation of the Kronecker delta
   $$\delta_{l,l'} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N e^{2\pi i (l'-l) n/N}$$
   we have
   $$\sum_n \sum_{l'} \alpha_{l'} e^{-i(k_l-k_{l'})na} =  \sum_{l'} \alpha_{l'} N \delta_{l,l'} = N \alpha_l$$
   and
   $$\sum_n \sum_{l'} \alpha^\dagger_{l'} e^{-i(k_l+k_{l'})na} =  \sum_{l'} \alpha^\dagger_{l'} N \delta_{-l,l'} = N \alpha^\dagger_{-l}$$
   as desired.
2. To find $\alpha_l$ we need to invert the given relations. Since the these relations take the form of a Fourier series, what Tong does is the most natural. Other methods will amount to the same thing.

Comment: Ah, so there was a typo, $a_l$ should probably have been $a_{l'}$ in the original test, right? Otherwise the wrong index is contracted.

Comment: Yes, there must be a typo either in the text or in your transcription of it.